# Java Web App Deployment Issues in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am still having issues deploying my JavaWeb app. However here is a interesting tidbit. I was able to Deploy the app in MCF. However try to access the app thru the URL failed. I ssh'd to the box as vcap, and did a look at all the processes. And the tomcat process was indeed running. Then I found out the local ip of the MCF box. I also ps & greped for startup (Thats the command I believe is used to start the tomcat). And there was one such process with a port  (-p 49922). I then went to my machine opened safari, can connected at the port, and low and behold the app was indeed running.

This is the same behavior I am seeing on cloudfoundry.com as well as MCF. However on CloudFoundry I cannot SSh so I have no way of knowing this is what is happening. I can attach the push logs (-t) . It shows this on vmc apps

```
+-------------+----+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| Application | #  | Health | URLS                            | Services |
+-------------+----+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| delements   | 1  | 0%     | delements.xxxxx.cloudfoundry.me | cfdb     |
+-------------+----+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

But I know its running, just not accessible. Has anyone else seen this behavior. Whats Going on.

Thanks
Atul

Comment: Do you have any application logs (`vmc logs delements`)? If not have, have a look at the tomcat logs in your mcf install, that may give a hint.

Comment: I did that. No hints there. Is there another location I should be looking at on the MCF. I do not know where all the logs or the inbound request is first handled.

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the CF support ticket, please try not to set the data source connection properties and let CF auto-reconfigure the datasource bean. For detailed doc please visit: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html